# What is the meaning of "She is right about that!"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "She is right about that!" in the following sentence (Source: PHONICS PC COMICS Volume 3 Issue 1),

> Mom stomps downstairs to the kitchen.
>
> Quick, Zak! Where are the GROW buttons on our super shrinker belts?
>
> I cannot find them, Zane! Shhh! Mom is coming back! Oooo!
>
> This is gross!
>
> **She is right about that!**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speaker is simply agreeing with his mother's comment, expressing disgust at the sticky mess of peanut butter.It could be paraphrased as "Indeed it is!", although the register wouldn't be quite right for this context, which appears to be a children's comic for early learners.